# jQuery data-table, Search a exact word(not substring) in a comma separated string(column value)

Tags: jquery, datatable

I want to filter an exact word in a comma delimited string(column value)

For example,

String : [CST,CS,ATS,ALU]
search input : CS

Here,

I need list of row that has only CS and should not have CST.

Could you please help me resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: What does your code look like so far? do you have a test set of data? Is the only criteria that CTS and CS are mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
    // array declaration
    var stringArray = ["CST", "CS", "ATS", "ALU"];
    // using jQuery.inArray gives us the position of the item
    var indexFound = $.inArray( "CS", stringArray);
    // put the item found on that index on the variable 'itemFound'
    var itemFound = stringArray[indexFound];
```

I hope it's what you needed, ***`this is my first help here! :P`***

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Remember that your username is not permanent, and you can update it when you like